# Database Triggered Cloud Functions across multiple Firebase projects

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to trigger a cloud function on a database instance of another firebase project? From what I've read so far, the documents mention passing an instance name in the function but this would be an instance in the same project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. Both functions and database shards must be contained within a single project.